# Make multiple plots on a same axis scale

Tags: r, plot

How should I force R to make multiple plots but all on the same axis (X and Y) scale? I made some individual plots with R which present the position of particles based on an X and Y. I am trying to make all of them with exactly the same scale. The way that I'm plotting is via png command, something like:

```
png(paste0("tile.png"),width=25.0,height=30.0,units="cm",res=240)
```

and I am applying this to the others but the scale is going to be changed. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: try `xlim` and `ylim`

Comment: It's not about the `png` call, but about the `plot` call. Set the same limits there using `xlim` and `ylim` as Jimbou suggested.